# Attempted import error when importing static function / class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made the class in `MyTool.js` in the same directory as my `Component.js`

```
export class MyTool {
    constructor(){
      
    }
  
    numToBar(num){
      if (num == 0) {return 8;}
      if (num == 1) {return 16;}
      if (num == 2) {return 24;}
      if (num == 3) {return 32;}
      if (num == 4) {return 64;}
      if (num == 5) {return 128;}
      if (num == 6) {return 256;}
      if (num == 7) {return 512;}
    }
    barToNum(bar){
      if (bar == 8) {return 0;}
      if (bar == 16) {return 1;}
      if (bar == 24) {return 2;}
      if (bar == 32) {return 3;}
      if (bar == 64) {return 4;}
      if (bar == 128) {return 5;}
      if (bar == 256) {return 6;}
      if (bar == 512) {return 7;}
    }
}
```

and then import it in my `Component.js` and use as static class

```
import MyTool from './MyTool.js';

MyTool.numToBar(3);
```

But there comes error like this

```
Attempted import error: './MyTool.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'MyTool').
```

Where should I fix??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `default` to your class definition:

```
export default class MyTool {
    constructor(){
      
    }
  
    numToBar(num){
      if (num == 0) {return 8;}
      if (num == 1) {return 16;}
      if (num == 2) {return 24;}
      if (num == 3) {return 32;}
      if (num == 4) {return 64;}
      if (num == 5) {return 128;}
      if (num == 6) {return 256;}
      if (num == 7) {return 512;}
    }
    barToNum(bar){
      if (bar == 8) {return 0;}
      if (bar == 16) {return 1;}
      if (bar == 24) {return 2;}
      if (bar == 32) {return 3;}
      if (bar == 64) {return 4;}
      if (bar == 128) {return 5;}
      if (bar == 256) {return 6;}
      if (bar == 512) {return 7;}
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you I just miss the `default`,  However there comes another error `TypeError: _MyTool_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_21__.default.numToBar is not a function`

Comment: Ah it works I need to add 'static' to method name

Comment: because you haven't instantiated the class yet. start with `const tool = new MyTool(); tool.barToNum`

Comment: Thank you @Nick I use static though.